# Двусторонняя печать в Google Chrome из JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, печать

Как принудительно поставить галочку "Двусторонняя печать" в Google Chrome из JavaScript при выполнении `window.print()`?
Или есть ключ при запуске Google Chrome, который по умолчанию ставит эту галочку?

Comment: А эта опция с прошлого раза не сохраняется? Насколько я помню, все параметры печати лежат в конфиге в профиле. Вот сейчас нажал Ctrl+P, переключил принтер и флажок стоит.

Comment: Компьютер многопользовательский и пользователи постоянно меняются. Под каждым сохранять нет желания.

Comment: Эм.. А не проще тогда всегда с новым чистым профилем запускать, если между пользователями не должны параметры сохраняться?

Comment: Как вариант. А где на диске chrome хранит свои настройки для пользователя? Чтобы в чистый профиль сразу добавить этот файл с предустановками.